# Make first section be open on load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

code on jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/fL9s0p81/

HTML:

```
 <body>
     <div class="accordion horizontal">
         <section id="about">
             <h2><a href="#about">About Me</a></h2>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. .</p>
        </section>

        <section id="services">
            <h2><a href="#services">Services</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="blog">
            <h2><a href="#blog">Blog</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="portfolio">
            <h2><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
        </section>

        <section id="contact">
            <h2><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav,         section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
 audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
 [hidden] { display: none; }
 html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
 body { margin: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.231; width: 980px;}
 body, button, input, select, textarea { font-family: sans-serif; color: #222; }

/*Define Accordion box*/
.accordion { width:980px; overflow:hidden; margin:10px auto; color:#474747; background:#fff; padding:10px; }

 /*General Accordion****************************************************************************/
/*Set style of open slide*/
.accordion section:target { background:#FFF; padding:10px;}
.accordion section:target:hover { background:#FFF; }
.accordion section:target h2 {width:100%;}
.accordion section:target h2 a{ color:#333; padding:0;}
.accordion section:target p {display:block;}
.accordion section h2 a{padding:8px 10px;display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;color:#eee; text-decoration:none; }

/*set style of closed slide*/
.accordion section{ float:left; overflow:hidden; color:#333; cursor:pointer; background: #333; margin:3px; }
.accordion section:hover {background:#444;}
.accordion section p { display:none; }
.accordion section:after{position:relative;font-size:24px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;}
.accordion section:nth-child(1):after{content:'';}
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after{content:'';}
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after{content:'';}
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after{content:'';}
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after{content:'';}
 /*End General Accordion****************************************************************************/

/*Horizontal Accordion *********************************************************************/
.horizontal section{ width:5%; height:550px; 
-moz-transition:width 0.2s ease-out; 
-webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
}

/*Position the number of the slide*/
.horizontal section:after{top:140px;left:15px;}

/*Header of closed slide*/
.horizontal section h2 { 
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
width:240px; position:relative; left:-100px; top:85px;
}

/*On mouse over open slide*/
.horizontal :target{ width:73%;height:530px; }
.horizontal :target h2{ top:0px;left:0;
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
/*Style      sections*******************************************************************/

#about {
background-color: #78C0F9;
color: #fff;
}

#services {
background-color: #88A61B;
color: #fff;
}

#blog{
background-color: #F29F05;
color: #fff;
}

#portfolio {
background-color: #F25C05;
color: #fff;
}

#contact {
background-color: #D92525;
color: #fff;
}

#about a, #services a, #blog a, #portfolio a, #contact a {
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
}

/*Style sections*****************************************************************/
```

My question is if I can do it strictly using only html5 and css3? if not, could you please help me with some js?

I only found another question similar to my one and the answer was something like (in my case) add #about to the link. That does work, but I'd like more of a professional solution, not just skip the problem.

Cheers.

Comment: using #about on the link is just loading the element on the page with the id "about", that may be your simplest solution if it works fine for you.

Comment: it is a simple solution and it works fine.. I just don't consider it as being a professional solution for what I need to do.

Comment: @Grundy - Thanks for the link to the duplicate. It does help with my problem (at least the js part - haven't tried the css solution yet). Sorry for the duplicate then, most likely I didn't knew how to search for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just overwrite the CSS again? Something like

```
#about h2 {
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
}

#about {
    width: 73%;
    height: 530px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#about p {display:block}
```

Comment: Did you tried to click another item ?